# Android Studio class name autocomplete suggestion red in color

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I couldn't help but notice that some of the class names autocomplete suggestions in Android Studio is red in color. [image: SCREENSHOT]

I'm curious to know why.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

Go File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart

This usually solves the problem.

Comment: Why all the suggestions are not red?